# Org Mode beamer link export to PDF

Tags: pdf, org-mode

Is there a way to embed hyperlinks to external documents in a beamer presentation, and have the links appear when you export an Org-Mode document to PDF, via Latex?

I see documentation for this functionality in HTML export, but just inserting `[[file:external_movie.avi]]` doesn't work with pdf export.  I've not yet had any luck
trying to put in `\url` Latex commands in the Org file.

Answers to a [similar question on Tex site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/best-practices-for-latex-code-in-org-mode-beamer-especially-url-links) don't work for me; putting in explicit
`\url` commmands just yields plain text.

I'd like to be able to open up the PDF file, and then click on the link in that file and have the movie open up.

Emacs-version: 24.3.1

Org-version: 7.9.3f

```
#+TITLE:     <<title>>
#+AUTHOR:    Author
#+EMAIL:     e@mail
#+DATE:      <<date>>
#+DESCRIPTION:
#+KEYWORDS:
#+LANGUAGE:  en
#+OPTIONS:   H:3 num:t toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc toc:nil \n:nil
#+INFOJS_OPT: view:nil toc:t ltoc:t mouse:underline buttons:0 path:http://orgmode.org/org-info.js
#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+LINK_UP:   
#+LINK_HOME: 
#+XSLT:

#+startup: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{pgfpages}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[letterpaper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]

#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+COLUMNS: %40ITEM %10BEAMER_env(Env) %9BEAMER_envargs(Env Args) %4BEAMER_col(Col)    %10BEAMER_extra(Extra)


* Presentation

** Slide 1
- Bullet
  - [[file:/path/to/file]]
  - sub bullet

- Bullet
```

Comment: Works for me in both Org-mode 7.9.3f (shipped with Emacs 24.3) and 8.2.3c (available from ELPA); the exported PDF contains a clickable link in place of `[[file:/path/to/target]]`. What goes wrong when you try it? (Also, it'd help to add to your question a snippet from your Org-mode file, showing the link markup you're expecting to export, as well as the results of `M-: (org-version)` and `M-: (emacs-version)` -- if your version of Emacs or Org-mode is especially old, that may be the cause of the problem.)

Comment: Right; works with vanilla Org-file.  I'm having problems with a beamer file; Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: I don't have the `pgfpages` package, but when I remove the two lines which make reference to it and then export to PDF from Org 7.9.3f, I do indeed get a PDF containing a clickable link to `/path/to/file`. Not sure what to tell you -- maybe it's something to do with `pgfpages`? I can't see how, but...

Comment: @AaronMiller removing pgfpages worked; note: I just copied the header info from an org-mode site, so I never identified an explicit need for that package.  You should copy your comment as an answer.

Comment: `pgfpages` appears to be a LaTeX package providing macros to easily do 2-up, 4-up, &c. (multiple pages on one sheet), as well as scaling to different paper sizes. Glad to know that change solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the pgfpages package, but when I remove the two lines which make reference to it and then export to PDF from Org 7.9.3f, I do indeed get a PDF containing a clickable link to /path/to/file. Not sure what to tell you -- maybe it's something to do with pgfpages? I can't see how, but...